# What is the dimension of the space $V$ of all matrices $S$

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $A$ represents the orthogonal projection onto a plane $R \in \mathbb{R^3}$. What is the dimension of the space $V$ of all matrices $S$ such that:

$$AS = S \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

I'm honestly not sure how to complete the exercise. I know the dimension is the number of vectors in a basis for $V$, but I don't see how the matrix itself lends insight into the dimension of $V$.

Comment: What is $V$? It is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, a plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$, or the space of matrices satisfying the given equation?

Comment: You used the letter $V$ to mean two different things. Which are you asking about?

Comment: I am also unsure about your usage of the letter $V$. I don't understand what you are trying to represent.

Comment: @anomaly sorry, I changed it.

Comment: Is $A$ equal to that $3 \times 3$ matrix on the RHS?

Comment: @amcalde I don't think so. Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

If $S=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbf{v}_1&\mathbf{v}_2&\mathbf{v}_3\end{array}\right)$, then 
$$S \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbf{v}_1&\mathbf{v}_2&\mathbf{0}\end{array}\right).$$
That means $$A\mathbf{v}_1=\mathbf{v}_1,A\mathbf{v}_2=\mathbf{v}_2,A\mathbf{v}_3=0.$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Does this make the dimension $6$? Are we trying to find how many vectors **v_1** and **v_2** such that $Av_1=v_1$ and $Av_2=v_2$?

Comment: Yes. Note that $A$ is a projection onto a plane $R$. So there is one dimension from $\mathbf{v}_3$, and $2$ dimensions from each $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$. I think $\dim V=5$.

Comment: I really wished you had worked more of the problem out. I'm having a hard time following the reasoning.